# Which major philosophers (if any) prior to the 1900s believed that consciousness was an emergent property of the brain?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, history

I am going to be doing an Independent Study with one of my professors, and I am obligated (due to the professor's expertise) to choose a philosopher prior to the 1900s.

Were there any philosophers that did not assume a dualistic model of consciousness prior to the 1900s?

Comment: Pretty much everybody, other than Descartes, either assumed a non-dualisitic model, in most cases idealistic, or dismissed the question as empirically vacuous. What you seem to want is rather a materialistic view of mind. The sense of "emergent" you use is a recent invention, and I am not sure you intend what it means, in any case, the reducible/emergent dichotomy is largely moot before 1900. You can look at mechanistic materialists like [La Mettrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julien_Offray_de_La_Mettrie), the author of Man a Machine, and Descartes's nemesis.

Comment: @Conifold I do indeed intend to use "emergent" in the sense of the generally accepted definition of most modern philosophers.

Comment: Before 1900 philosophers did not distinguish between  reduction and supervenience, it dates to [Morgan in 1920-s](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/supervenience/#OrigTerm), so you will not get a chance to use it, although you could try [emergentists like Mill](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties-emergent/#JSMil) (he was an empiricist though). See also [Wolfe on Diderot](https://philarchive.org/archive/WOLMAT-7v1) and [Shofield's book on British materialists](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt13x0zhv).

Comment: Many in East and West. For the East, see either https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey or here http://consciouslivingfoundation.org/ebooks/13/CLF-HistoryOfIndianPhilosophy.pdf